# Select all items in ul li with custom toggle switch on

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to create a custom toggle switch which when turned on it will select all elements of ul li and when off unselectes all elemets of ul li .similarly individual selection and multi selection and unselection should also work on list elements.stuck up with all these functionality together plz help.

```js
 $('#projects-menu').append("<li  value='sales1' class='disabled'>Sales 1</li>")
  $('#projects-menu').append("<li  value='sales2'>Sales 2</li>")
 $('#projects-menu').append("<li  value='sales3'>Sales 3</li>")

$('#projects-menu').on('click', 'li', function() {
          $("#projects-menu li").removeClass('selected');
          $(this).addClass('selected');
        })
```

```css
ul.menu {
            margin-top: 30px;
            list-style-type: none;
        }

        ul.menu li {
            background-color: #e0e0e0;
            padding: 8px 12px;
            border: solid 2px white;
            cursor: pointer;
            border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }

        ul.menu li:hover {
            background-color: #A9A9A9;
        }

        ul.menu li.selected {
            background-color: #23ac61;
        }



        ul.menu li.disabled:hover {
            background-color: #e0e0e0;
            cursor:default;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="projects">
        <ul class="menu" id="projects-menu">
        </ul>
 </div>

 <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input switchc" id="customSwitch2" checked>
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch2">Toggle me</label>
 </div>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "selecting" the `li`s? They are list items so they cannot be selected by default, and you don't seem to be adding any code to do any sort of selection? Please edit your question to explain exactly what you are trying to do, so we can help

Comment: sorry.I updated the code with selection of list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `forEach` function and `querySelectorAll` method to get all the ul > li and apply selected class which you toggle your switch.

You need to `event delegation` in this since the `elements` are added dynamically to the `DOM`

If the toggle is ON and OFF you can checked this using jQuery [is](https://api.jquery.com/is/) function and [:checked](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) attribute

**Edit:** Since you have added that you want to do multi selection via holding onto `control` key and then `click` to do `multi selection` and similarly the `Un-selection` with Ctrl `key` pressed

**Live Demo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#projects-menu').append("<li  value='sales1'>Sales 1</li>")
  $('#projects-menu').append("<li  value='sales2'>Sales 2</li>")
  $('#projects-menu').append("<li  value='sales3'>Sales 3</li>")

  $(document).on('click', '#projects-menu > li', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.ctrlKey) {
      if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
      } else {
        $(this).addClass("selected");
      }
    } else {
      $("#projects-menu > li").removeClass("selected");
      $(this).addClass("selected");
    }
  });

  let getCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('#projects-menu > li') //get checkboxes UL
  $(document).on('change', '#customSwitch2', function() {
    var $this = $(this)
    getCheckboxes.forEach(function(o) {
      if ($this.is(':checked')) {
        $(o).addClass('selected');
      } else {
        $(o).removeClass('selected');
      }
    })
  })
})
```

```css
ul.menu {
  margin-top: 30px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul.menu li {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  border: solid 2px white;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

ul.menu li:hover {
  background-color: #A9A9A9;
}

ul.menu li.selected {
  background-color: #23ac61;
}

ul.menu li.disabled:hover {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="projects">
  <ul class="menu" id="projects-menu">
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input switchc" id="customSwitch2">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch2">Toggle me</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you..I wanted to add a multislection and unselection also which is were I am stuck

Comment: @kavya I have provided an answer based on the question asked => *Select all items in ul li with custom toggle switch on* - Let me know - i am not sure what you mean by multi selection

Comment: Yes..I have asked in the description about having select all and multi selection together is causing me difficulty

Comment: multiselection is selection of more then one list item with ctrl key pressed ..similarly the unselection with ctrl key pressed

Comment: @kavya See my updated answer - you can do now select them by pressing the `control` key and clicking on the select to add the class.

Comment: Can we do the unselection of each item with ctrl key also?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```js
function check_uncheck_checkbox(isChecked) {
    if(isChecked) {
        $('input[name="language"]').each(function() { 
            this.checked = true; 
        });
    } else {
        $('input[name="language"]').each(function() {
            this.checked = false;
        });
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divCheckAll">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkall" id="checkall" onClick="check_uncheck_checkbox(this.checked);" />Check All</div>
<br/>
<div id="divCheckboxList">
    <div class="divCheckboxItem"><input type="checkbox" name="language" id="language1" value="English" />English</div>
    <div class="divCheckboxItem"><input type="checkbox" name="language" id="language2" value="French" />French</div>
    <div class="divCheckboxItem"><input type="checkbox" name="language" id="language3" value="German" />German</div>
    <div class="divCheckboxItem"><input type="checkbox" name="language" id="language4" value="Latin" />Latin</div>
</div>
```

Hope will helpful

Comment: I dont want to use a checkbox .wanted to display as li item only